# change div with with php or jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to change div with either php or jquery the important is to change div width.

scenario:

I have div what i want if i click `<a>` `tag` *click me to inlarge the div* div must increase the width and when click the *click me to default width* div go back to the default width.

```
<div class="mydiv"> my content here </div>

<a class="inlarge" href="#">click me to inlarge the div</a>
<a class="default" href="#">click me to default width</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `animate` functyion or just `css` function to do this:-

```
$(function(){
$('.inlarge').click(function(){
    $('.mydiv').animate({'width':'100%'},1000);
});

 $('.default').click(function(){
     $('.mydiv').animate({'width':'80%'},1000);
  });
});
```

by css:-

```
$(function(){
  $('.inlarge').click(function(){
    $('.mydiv').css({'width':'100%'});
});

 $('.default').click(function(){
  $('.mydiv').css({'width':'80%'});
   });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/asdasdasdas/shE58/24/)

Comment: It was a joke, I saw u edit many times. But I can just see that you edited again :) You also spelled functyion wrong lol.

Comment: is that possible when the width extend the movement is from the right to left.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to change the `width` of the `div`.

Try this:

```
$('.inlarge').click(function () {
    $(".mydiv").css("width", "100%");
});
$('.default').click(function () {
    $(".mydiv").css("width", "50%");
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4c0wswdr/1/)**

Comment: thank's for your answer is this possible when the `div` extend from right to left?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.css` using jquery -

```
var width = $( ".mydiv" ).width(); // calculate default width
//alert(width);return false;
$('.inlarge').click(function(){
    $('.mydiv').css('width','100px'); // change 100px
});
$('.default').click(function(){
    $('.mydiv').css('width',width+'px');
});
```